# Aproximating the volume of a sphere by dividing it into infinitesimal cubes

Tags: integration, volume

I have spent hours trying to solve it by substituting into two right triangles, asked multiple teachers but none can answer... This is not a homework, its just out of pure curiosity. I did the same with a circle (divide it into infinitesimal squares and solved the integral and obtained the correct area of the area of a circle and I want to extend this in 3D to get the volume of a sphere. 
Basically the integral to solve is :

$$\iint \sqrt{r^2 - x^2 - z^2} dxdz$$

where $r$ is radius and $x$ and $z$ are in Cartesian coordinates

I'm not asking for a complete resolution, just the thechnique, I would like to continue working on it myself, I just want a helping hand.
I have also extended this integral to $N$-dimensions, but that's a project for the future.

On second thought, a full resolution would be nice... Thanks!

Comment: Try to consider a quartersphere...

Comment: Be wary that in $\geq 3$ dimensions, this method (subdivision) will not always work for computing surfaces. (I remember seeing a “paper lantern”-shaped counter-example, but sadly not the counter-example itself).

Comment: @LeonhardtvonM I think that's what i have been doing, I tried again but am still stuck, any more clues?

Comment: @Circonflexe: That's [Schwarz's cylinder area paradox](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jGdFP1FI_Ho). Computing volumes by subdivision is still fine though.

Comment: @ Investor : there is a fundamental mistake in the sentence "Aproximating the area of a sphere by dividing it into infinitesimal cubes" : one cannot aproximate an area with infinitesimal volumes, but with infinitesimal areas. First, one have to define the infinitesimal area to be sumed all over the surface of the sphere. To do that, it is much easier to use spherical coordinates than Cartesian. Also, the function in your double integral is false because $\sqrt{r^2-x^2-z^2}=y$ and suming $y.dx.dz$ is not an infinitesimal area on the surface of the sphere.

Comment: The mistake is corrected, sorry about that!

Comment: Regarding Schwarz's paradox, I suggest reading [this](http://fredrickey.info/hm/CalcNotes/schwarz-paradox.pdf).

Comment: http://scientificsentence.net/Electromagnetics/Mathematics/Volume-Element2.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For a sphere's surface area:**

Divide the sphere into square patches, much as you would with infinitesimals:
$$dA = \sin \theta R^2\ d\theta\ d\phi$$
$$\Delta A_{ij} 
= \sin \left(\frac{i\pi}{N}\right) \frac{\pi}{N}\frac{2\pi}{M}R^2$$
Now sum using the following identity:
$$\sum_{j = 1}^{N} \sin{(j \theta)} = \frac{\cos{\left (\frac{\theta}{2} \right)} - \cos{\left ((N + \frac{1}{2})\theta \right )}}{2 \sin{ \left ( \frac{\theta}{2} \right )}}R^2$$
So that:
$$S_{N,M} = \sum_{i=0,j=0}^{N,M}\sin \left(\frac{i\pi}{N}\right) \frac{\pi}{N}\frac{2\pi}{M} = \frac{2\pi^2}{N}
\frac{\cos{\left (\frac{\pi}{2N} \right)} - \cos{\left ((1 + \frac{1}{2N})\pi \right )}}{2 \sin{ \left ( \frac{\pi}{2N} \right )}}$$
Thus, using $\lim_{x\to 0} \sin x/ x = 1$ we have:
$$S=\lim_{N\to\infty} S_N = 4\pi R^2$$

**Addendum:**

Although this happens to give the correct result, as others have noted, the correct definition of the surface area is given by the Lebesgue Measure of the surface, which involving finding the infimum of all possible patch divisions.

**For a sphere's volume with cubes:**

To make life easier, start with a hemisphere of radius $R$, and divide into $N$ disks. The area of each disk can be calculated by your $2D$ method, and then summed up.

We have for each disk at height $h=i\cdot R/N$, a radius of $\sqrt{R^2−h^2}$, so that the volume of each disk is:
$$V_i = \pi (R^2-h^2)R/N$$
Now sum these up:

$$\frac{V_N}{2}\equiv\text{Hemisphere Vol.}=\sum_{i=1}^N  \frac{\pi R^3}{N} \left(1-\frac{i^2} {N^2}\right)$$
using the formula for sums of powers,
$$\sum_{k=1}^nk^2 = \frac{2n^3 + 3n^2 + n}{6}$$
We get:
$$V_N=2N\cdot \frac{\pi R^3}{N} +
2N\cdot\frac{\pi R^3}{N^3}\left(\frac{2N^3 + 3N^2 + N}{6}\right)$$
$$= \pi R^3 \cdot\left(\frac{4 N-1/N-3}{3 N}\right)$$
So that:
$$V\equiv \lim_{n\to\infty} V_N = \frac{4\pi R^3}{3}$$

Comment: Pretty sure they want surface area, not volume.

Comment: @user24142 - fixed.

Comment: @nbubis I made a mistake, volume is what i wanted sorry!

Comment: @Investor - see the edit.

Comment: @nbubis Sorry, my bad

Comment: I don't see where the i in h= i . R/N comes from?
also, how do you assume that h=iR/N?

Comment: @Investor - just divide the hemisphere into $N$ parts, $i$ is just the index, where $i=0$ is the first disk etc.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you very much!

Comment: @nbubis Although it helped, i don't understand how we got from the "to sum these up" expression to the "to get" expression.

Comment: @Investor - I added some detail. Also see:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number

Comment: I really don't understand the steps involved in the resolution of the integral in this manner... I just now started college. How does the sum of powers formula give the "to get" expression?

Comment: @Investor - please point out what art is not clear.

Comment: how do you apply the formula for the sum of powers to sum of the volumes of the disks? And then, how do you simplify that ("we get") expression to get the volume of a sphere?

Comment: @Investor - added some detail - it's only algebra.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23749/discussion-between-investor-and-nbubis).